# Select values from available list in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Following code works and display the desired results.
I like to select values for the SOURCE column only from **available** list in the reverse order, if there are multiple values.

```
import pandas as pd
available = ['a','b']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'SOURCE': ['x-a', 'b-y-z', 'c'] })
for entry in df['SOURCE']:
    if not  '-' in entry: continue
    for col in entry.split("-")[::-1]:
        if col in available:
            df.loc[ df['SOURCE'] == entry,'SOURCE'] = col
            break
print(df)

Output:
  SOURCE
0      a
1      b
2      c
```

Is there a more Pythonic way to do it?

Update: Characters are just place Holder for strings in actual problem.   If I don't find match in available list,  it should return the original value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.extract`:

```
pat = '|'.join(available[::-1])
df['SOURCE'] = df.SOURCE.str.extract(f'({pat})').fillna(df['SOURCE'])
```

Output:

```
  SOURCE
0      a
1      b
2      c
```

Comment: Pat fails to handle  multicharacter  items:   "available = ['a','b','p']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'SOURCE': ['x-pa', 'b-y-z', 'c', 'd'] })"     gives me 'p' in the output but I am expecting the original 'x-pa'.

Comment: I don't understand why `x-pa`? shouldn't it be `pa`? Anyway, if that's what you expect, you should update your question. My current solution matches your expected output **in the question** as of now.

Comment: Also are `available` always characters?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. 1.  Characters are place holders for string  in both the places. I will explicitly change data in future examples.   2.  If I don't find  match in in available list, it should return as it is.

Comment: Then I don't get why you have `c` in the expected output. On the other hand, `str.extract` returns `NaN` if matches can't be found, you can use `.notnull()` to extract from orginal values.

Comment: Or you can just use `.str.contains(pat)`.

Comment: Somehow I do not feel  comfortable going the 'pattern' way.   1.   I have 100s of such items.   2.  An item may be able to contain other item.     I am  looking for exact match.